# Showing equivalence of the cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that if H is a subgroup of index 2 in a finite group G, then every left coset of H is also right coset of H.

Thanks for your helps..

Comment: Are you aware that "index 2" means "has 2 cosets"?

Comment: Well how can we prove this claim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of $H$ being $2$ means that there are $2$ cosets. These are disjoint, their union gives the whole group $G$, and one of them is $H$ itself.

So, the remaining part $G\setminus H$ must be the other coset, even if we consider it as left or as right coset.

Answer (score 1):

$[G:H] = 2 \Longrightarrow G$ is being partitioned into $2$ disjoint cosets.  If $g \in H$, then $gH = Hg = H$.  Since there are only two partitions, then $g \notin H \Rightarrow gH = Hg = G$ \ $H$.

Therefore, for all $g \in G$, $gH = Hg$.